# create jquery array from php ajax response JSON object

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json, store

I have an **en.php** file with an array inside, like this:

```
$lang = array(
    // MENÚ LATERAL
    "bienvenido" => "Welcome",
    "panel_administracion" => "Administration panel",
    "administracion" => "Administration",
    "gestion_usuarios" => "Users Management",
    "roles_permisos" => "Roles and Permissions",
    "perfiles" => "Profiles",
    "apariencia" => "Appearance",
    "configuracion" => "Settings",
    "gestion_scripts" => "Script Management",
    "gestion_escenarios" => "Scenario Management",
    "planificador" => "Planner",
    "monitorizacion" => "Monitoring",
    "resultados_ejecuciones" => "Executions Results",
    "dashboard" => "Dashboard",
    // USUARIOS
    "usuario" => "User",
    "nombre_pagina" => "Users",
    "nuevo_usuario" => "New User",
    "nombre_usuario" => "User Name",
    "perfil" => "Profile",
    "rol" => "Role",
    "idioma_sitio" => "Language",
    "password" => "Password",
    "repetir_password" => "Repeat Password",
    "guardar" => "Save",
    "administracion_usuarios" => "User administration",
    "actualizar_usuario" => "Edit user",
    "acciones" => "Actions"
);
```

And I would like store this array in a js array, inside an .js file to access to data always I need, and this code do it this. But I receive this alert: *[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental*...

```
var traducciones = function () {
    var tmp = null;
    var action = "getTraducciones";
    $.ajax({
        'async': false,
        'type': "POST",
        'global': false,
        'dataType': 'html',
        'url': '../egea/lib/egeaAjax/fAjaxUsuarios.php',
        'data': { 'action': action },
        'success': function (data) {
            var datos = JSON.parse(data);
            tmp = datos;
        }
    });
    return tmp;
}();
```

PHP function:

```
function getTraducciones(){
    session_start();
    $traducciones = '';
    $u = $_SESSION['usuario'];
    if (isset($u) === true){
        $lang = getLanguage($u);
        if(isset($lang) === true){
            require "../../lang/".$lang.".php";
        }else{
            require "../../lang/es.php";
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($lang);
}
```

**NOTE:** async: false is deprecated.
How can I do it, without ajax *async:false* call?.
Thanks.

Comment: How about to use the `.then` function? This is how I handle JSON in JS sent from PHP: `$.ajax({type: 'POST', url: '<...>', data: { <...> }}).then(function(data) { <...> });`

Comment: Thanks Vertex but I receive "undefined"

Comment: Did you do a `echo json_encode($lang);` in your php file at the end?

Comment: Also REMOVE this: `'async': false` ... bad, don't do that. ... and fix the .ajax option for datatype to `dataType: 'json'` (so it knows its expecting json).

Comment: Thanks IncredibleHat, if I remove async:false, It isnt work, and I have put getTraducciones() function PHP code

Comment: Well, theres a few issues here, all working against you :) You also don't need `var datos = JSON.parse(data);` since if you set `dataType: 'json'`, then it already is in json too.

Comment: Also please make sure, that your PHP code responding correct JSON. I use [Postman Free](https://www.getpostman.com/apps) for that

Comment: I think I see where things are going terribly wrong and why you WANT async (which defeats this process, and causes the depreciated error). You are trying to return `tmp` before its even set by the ajax call. `success` is a callback function, which happens after ajax gets its response (which is going to be after `traducciones` completes). You'll need to either assign a global scoped variable in the callback... or set a promise... or rethink why you need tmp syncronously in the first place ?

Comment: I highly recommend using the well established PO format for translations instead of building your own version of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return promise instead of the value itself:

```
var traducciones = function () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var action = "getTraducciones";
        $.ajax({
            'async': true,
            'type': "POST",
            'global': false,
            'dataType': 'html',
            'url': '../egea/lib/egeaAjax/fAjaxUsuarios.php',
            'data': { 'action': action },
            'success': function (data) {
                var datos = JSON.parse(data);
                resolve(datos);
            },
            'error': reject
        });
    });
}();
```

Then use it like:

```
traducciones.then(function(datos) {
    // the code that uses the data
}, function() {
    // code called if data loading failed
});
```

---

By the way, if you really need to have the data loaded in a synchronous way, you may consider loading it as a JS code instead of JSON – i.e. replace:

```
echo json_encode($lang);
```

in your PHP code with:

```
Header('Content-type: text/javascript; charset=utf-8');
    // or whatever other charset you are using ^^^^^
echo "var traducciones = " . json_encode($lang) . ";\n";
```

And then load it as a normal script:

```
<script src="../egea/lib/egeaAjax/fAjaxUsuarios.php"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks jaboga, but How can I iterate to get the values?:

Comment: jQuery should allow you to iterate over an object exactly like over an Array.